# The best way to lock commands in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a few commands in Symfony that are triggered by cron. I recently I added the LockHandler to make sure that there is only one command running at the time however I find it even more troublesome. Here is one of the scenarios that I came across today:

1. There is a command that gets triggered by cron: $lock = new LockHandler('someprocess');
2. It shouldn't take more than 15 mins to finish it however I notice after  a few hours that the processed hasn't been running for hours.
3. When I try to run the command manually it tells me that there is another instance already running.

So in this kind of situation I suspect two things:

1. The command ran, locked the process but due to an error it stopped and never released the lock.
2. It was a timeout and it also stopped without releasing the lock.

What would be the best practice to prevent this issue?

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

    $lock = new LockHandler('someproccess');

    if (!$lock->lock()) {
        $output->writeln('This command is already running in another process.');

        return 0;
    }

    $this->dosomething();

    $lock->release();
}
```

Comment: introduce heartbeat thread, which will update lock and if there is no update for last X minutes - release lock

Comment: If there's an error or timeout you should get something in the symfony logs? Fix the error, wrap `$this->doSomething()` inside a try-catch-finally block and release the lock in the `finally`-part.

Comment: Thank you @Lashane.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs @ccKep unfortunately.

Comment: @Lashane, I created some functionality that checks how long the command has been running for and for testing purposes I set the timeout to 1 second. If the timeout is reached I run the release function but it doesn't seem to release the lock. Any ideas?

Comment: it could be anything, add debug logging everywhere to see what is actually going on